# qsort sorting lines, getting unfreed blocks

Tags: c, free

The problem is - I'm trying to sort several lines using qsort, everything works in the outfile. Unfortunately `valgrind` gives me errors about not freeing some memory blocks.

At first I thought - I need to `free(lines)` but it is already there. What am I missing?

```
qsort(lines, linenumber, sizeof(char*), compare_string);
 for(c=0; c<linenumber; c++) {
    fputs(lines[c], outfile);
 }
 free(lines);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you assign memory to lines? If it is a two-dimensional array then you have to malloc each line separately in a for loop.

Do something like this-

```
for(counter=Max_lines;counter>0;counter--){
     free(lines[counter]);
}
```